# git: 'remote-https' is not a git command?

Tags: git, https

Whenever I attempt to clone, push or pull I get:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Project>git pull
```

`git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Committing and adding still work fine.

Comment: Please add the command you entered to get this output.

Comment: Check your git installation, under `libexec\git-core`, is there a `git-remote-https.exe`?

Comment: @jingx I've updated git to the latest version, how can I check my git installation, should I have a local file?

Comment: Consider updating your version of git? What version are you running? v1.6?

Comment: In my Windows I found `git-remote-https.exe` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core`

Comment: On linux this worked for me: ```sudo apt-get install git```

Answer (score 59):

In my case, I was building Git from source in WSL Ubuntu.

The distribution didn't come with `libcurl` preinstalled. In this case, the `git-remote-http` executable was not being built. So I installed it:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then, I re-configured, re-`make`d and re-installed, and Git could clone.

Comment: And btw, on RHEL systems, the equivalent is `yum/dnf install libcurl-devel`

Comment: I got same issue on CentOS7 after I build git from source code. This is working for me. Thank you.

Comment: Same issue here, this one fix the issue for me. It is strange that git does not show any warning noticing me that libcurl should be installed. I think using https for git clone is pretty common nowadays.

Comment: Works for me on CentOS 8.3

Comment: On Debian, I had to install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`, recompile Git, then it worked

Answer (score 49):

I was using Entware and had installed git using `opkg install git` and was getting this error.
Installing `git-http` fixed it for me, i.e. `opkg install git-http`. This also helps on OpenWrt based systems.

Comment: Same with OpenWRT.

Comment: Excellent. I used this on my TNAS. Great answer. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

I was also having this error, and solved it by running this command:

`path %path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin`

This added the folder where my `git-remote-https.exe` file was stored.

Answer (score 7):

Today, I was facing the same problem. The problem in my case was wrong path set in android studio to the git execution file. I changed the path of git execution and it worked. According to my git installation the path was **C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe**. I used this path in android studio. By using below steps

1. File
2. Setting
3. version control
4. git
   And I pasted the above mentioned path in **Path to git exectable**

and done.

Hope this helps other.

Comment: "git.path": "C:/Your/Maybe/Not/Default/Path/git.exe" on Windows/VSCode. There you set it on the settings.json VScode file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I solved by installing the latest version of Git for Windows at https://gitforwindows.org/. This might not be the correct solution for everyone. I had recently uninstalled Git for Windows not realizing that my git GUI, SourceTree, was using it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the **URL** from **.git/config** file.

In my case, the error was the remote origin location

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = "CHECK THIS LOCATION"
```

I guess the remote location is something like this and the unknown git command 'remote-https' came from an invalid combination of 'remote' + 'https'

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repo
```

Answer (score 2):

> Note:
>
> - If after build and install `git` from the latest source code, this issue is occurred, continue..
> - If not, just ignore this answer..

Check the command `git-remote-https` existed or not in your `git` install path. For me, after build from source and `make install`, I can check that by

```
=---------------------=
│git on  HEAD (cd3e6062)
-> ls /usr/local/bin/git*
```

If that command not existed in path, copy the `git-remote-https` built from your git source code path to your `git` install path,

```
=---------------------=
│git on  HEAD (cd3e6062)
-> sudo cp git-remote-https /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

This points at an incomplete -- or otherwise busted -- installation. Git is looking for -- and is unable to find -- one of its auxiliary executables: `git-remote-https`.

If you used some sort of installer on Windows, try rerunning the installation... If you built it from source -- make sure to let the build process do the install itself, rather than manually copying `git.exe` (and omitting all the other binaries it needs).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing with the git 2.18.0 or higher version. I downgraded to 2.17.* and it seems to solve the problem. My issue was running git clone through https.

Comment: I'm using recent Git version (2.28.0) and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but mine was a bit different situation, when I added a git remote there was I typo in url's https part, so it would give me the same error, always go ahead and check your remote urls from cmd with git remote -v

Make sure that the provided url is the same from Github.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a windows 10 update created some registry blocker (which were left behind after the update)

I just needed to delete the following registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\git-remote-https.exe]
"Debugger"="\"C:\\windows\\SoftwareDistribution\\Download\\Install\\patchmypc-preventstart.exe\" /StopProcess /ApplicationName=\"git-remote-https.exe\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue on Ubuntu. However, I was able to resolve the problem by installing Git directly on the base system rather than relying on Conda's version. If you're facing a similar issue, consider installing Git on your base system as it might help resolve the problem.