# git: 'remote-addhttps' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I am getting this error when trying to commit my local repository to github.I was doing version control through visual studio and was committing the final project to my remote repository when i get this error.
After the command- git push -u origin master i get this error

Comment: Have you added a remote?

Comment: Yes i did. I did it again just to make sure to which it responds by saying that remote already exists@ParthShah

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366101/git-remote-https-is-not-a-git-command) solve your issue?

Comment: When i entered the exact command which is given i get the error  => bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('  @ParthShah

Comment: I have tried reinstalling git bash and visual studio code and restarted the machine after installation but still the same error continues to come

Comment: You need to add git to your PATH, I think. Follow the link I posted.

Comment: I solved the error! I created two remotes which were interrupting the commit process. Thank you for your help!