# Problems installing Brew on MacOS: Git 'remote-https' is not a git command

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I would like to install brew on my laptop (Mac), git version 2.39.2. However, when I try:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)
```

Results in ->:

```
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R xxx:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin
```

`

I think the installation of git is not correct, but how to fix this?

I try to install brew, and used the commands from the https://brew.sh/index_nl page.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)
```

It is not possible to install brew and update git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366101/git-remote-https-is-not-a-git-command

Comment: fyi this really should be posted to [apple.se] - it's off-topic here (not a programming question)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install XCode Command Line Tools before installing Homebrew - CLT includes a basic Git client, which you can then replace with one from Homebrew. (This is mentioned in the Homebrew installation docs: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)